# Convert HTML form-data to nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, nested, form-data

I am trying to convert form-data which fields names are referencing a nested JSON structure into a JSON object. The object representing form-data is:

```
{
    "custom[1].a": "FIXED",
    "custom[1].b": "",
    "custom[1].c": "PROPORTIONATE",
    "custom[1].d": ""
    "custom[2].a": "FIXED2",
    "custom[2].b": "",
    "custom[2].c": "PROPORTIONATE2",
    "custom[2].d": ""
}
```

I want to convert it to an object that can be stringify to.

```
"customConfiguration": [
     {
        "a": "PROPORTIONATE",
        "b": "",
        "c": "FIXED",
        "d": ""
    },
    {   "a": "PROPORTIONATE2",
        "b": "",
        "c": "FIXED2",
        "d": ""
    }]
```

Comment: is `custom[2].c` a string? and should custom became an array? starting from `1`?

Comment: neither of above is JSON/JavaScript object

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON. Is that the actual data or is it some sort of console display?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, now i have corrected the question.

Comment: your edit does not help. the "JSON" is no one. and now the wanted result is missing.

Comment: Now is it clear ? @NinaScholz

Comment: how do you go from `[1]` to index `0`? is the count based on one?

Comment: yes the count is based on 1.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want. Assuming that numbers indicate an array index and while one based, decrement the index for a zero based result.

- iterates over all keys of the object with reduce, starts with an empty object
- replace `[` with `.[`, splits the key in parts, so strings with `[...]` indicates array values and the others are usual properties
- applies a reduce for the right property reference, starts with the object of the first reduce

  - checks if item is an array index, if so decrement by 1, make it zero based
  - applies to the property the property or if the next part is an array index, then return an array otherwise an object
  - check if the key is the last key in the array and assign the value
  - return the new object reference
- return the new object

```js
var object = {
        'custom[1].a': 'PROPORTIONATE',
        'custom[1].b': '',
        'custom[1].c': 'FIXED',
        'custom[1].d': '',
        'custom[2].a': 'PROPORTIONATE2',
        'custom[2].b': '',
        'custom[2].c': 'FIXED2',
        'custom[2].d': ''
    },
    newObject = Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.replace('[', '.[').split('.').reduce(function (o, b, i, kk) {
            function isArrayIndex(s) { return /^\[\d+\]$/.test(s); }                
            if (isArrayIndex(b)) {
                b = b.match(/\d+/) - 1;
            }
            o[b] = o[b] || (isArrayIndex(kk[i + 1]) ? [] : {});
            if (i + 1 === kk.length) {
                o[b] = object[a];
            }
            return o[b];
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, {});

    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newObject, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```